# Get all the nodes of webforms treeview by httpwebrequest

Tags: asp.net, treeview, httpwebrequest

I want to get all the nodes of a websites which is created by asp.net webforms.  The TreeView has at least 3 levels, and its initial `expandDepth` is 1.

Here's what the TreeView looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WaCq.png

and here's the code:

```
var rqst = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://localhost:9418/Index.aspx");
var rspn = (HttpWebResponse)rqst.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rspn.GetResponseStream(),Encoding.UTF8))
    Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

If I view the page source directly in the browser, I can see all the nodes.
You can get the code files here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Al1hUSZtR4OjwU_kmegzF5gzFIKp